# Do posts deleted/locked by community appear in the user's "deleted posts" list?

Tags: support

One of my post was deleted by [community](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/-1/community).

Here is my post: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14524/leaving-a-comment-or-upvoting-existing-one-after-downvoting-a-post-except-spa

Does it appear in user deleted list ? For me its not.

If not visible, how can I find the post which was deleted by community.

*I got that post link from a mod*

Comment: @kos https://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=user%3A439451+is%3Aq+deleted%3A1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Recently deleted questions" and "Recently deleted answers" lists include only posts not older than 60 days;

Just two hours ago a feature that allows 10K+ users to search through all of their old posts (including deleted posts) using the search function [has been announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270562/302251);

To get the full list of deleted questions:

```
user:me is:q deleted:1
```

To get the full list of deleted answers:

```
user:me is:a deleted:1
```

But unluckily you don't have enough reputation yet to do that, so no, until you'll have at least 10K reputation you won't be able to see deleted posts of yours older than 60 days.

Comment: nope, its not there :) It showing all my 15 posts which are available at my profile.

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/439451/ravan?tab=questions

Comment: For me its different : http://imgur.com/pF82LW4

Comment: I can't see deleted posts with `user:439451 deleted:1` . It showing 18 posts (15 Q + 3 A) which are not deleted.

Comment: yeah sure =)...